# how to get rows element of DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView in foreach loop

Tags: devexpress, asp.net-3.5

I am used Dev Express.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView control in my application ,
I want to hide the visibility of link button and anchor tag which in DataItemTemplate of ASPGridview.

I did this like as

```
protected void objGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow dr in objGrid.Rows)
    {
        LinkButton objedit = (LinkButton)dr.FindControl("lnbEdit");
        objedit.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

but I get error becouse objGrid has no property or methos of rows.
so, how to use foreach for ASPxGridview of DevExpress control as databound event in asp.net 3.5 C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowCellTemplateControltopic) to access controls defined in DataCellTemplate.

Comment: ya but how to use foreach loop for that conrol ,becoz i want hide control base on condition .

Comment: You don't need to use foreach loop, you can use this method in event handler that is triggered for every row. Look at the example at the bottom of link I posted where HtmlDataCellPrepared event is used.

Comment: i followed this link example but i get null value of my Linkbutton conrol LinkButton objedit = (LinkButton)objGrid.FindRowTemplateControl(1, "lnbEdit");

Comment: I posted a link to FindRow>>>Cell<<<TemplateControl and you are using FindRowTemplateControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/3747/components/grid-view/concepts/edit-data/validate-grid-data):

```
protected void grid_RowValidating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataValidationEventArgs e) {
    foreach (GridViewColumn row in grid.Columns) {
        GridViewDataColumn dataRow = row as GridViewDataColumn;
        if (dataRow == null) continue;
        if (e.NewValues[dataRow.FieldName] == null)
            e.Errors[dataRow] = "Value cannot be null.";
    }
    if (e.NewValues["FirstName"] != null &&
        e.NewValues["FirstName"].ToString().Length < 6) {
        e.Errors[(GridViewDataColumn)grid.Columns["FirstName"]] = "Field value must be at least six characters long.";
    }
    if (e.Errors.Count > 0) e.RowError = "Please fill in all fields.";
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?